# Filling holes on the bottom of scanned design?

Tags: faces, 3d-printing

I'm very, very new to Blender, and for an assignment, I've used the Trnio app to create a 3D image of a stuffed animal that I then imported into Blender. This is the result (as you can see, Trnio also scanned in the floor that the animal was sitting on):

[image]

The scanned bit of the floor aside, my problem is that the bottom of the animal wasn't scanned, as it was on the floor, and so I get this opening below:

[image]

My task is to both close the bottom of my design while also cleaning up a bit of the extra floor. But I can't seem to close my gap. I've tried selecting vertices, but this took a very long time and turned out to be quite a mess. I'm not really sure what the solution is, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: You can find several [fill methods](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I've found that doing it piecemeal, fixes the issue, i.e.

- selecting the open area's vertices using ALT+LClick on an edge of the open loop
- deselecting half of it with using Box select
- press F to seal it with a new face,
- then selecting the remaining open half and hitting F to seal it